# A second isomorphism theorem for action on cosets

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group, and $K$, $L$ subgroups of $G$ such that $G = KL=LK$.
Let $\Omega = G/K$ and $\pi: G \to S_{\Omega}$ the canonical action on cosets.

> **Question**: Is it true that $\forall g \in G$ $\exists l \in L $ such that $\pi(g)=\pi(l)$ ?

If yes, then $\forall k \in K$ $\exists s \in K \cap L $ such that $\pi(k)=\pi(s)$, because $ker(\pi) \subset K$.

Comment: See the augmented post:  [A second isomorphism theorem for action on cosets II](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/692813/a-second-isomorphism-theorem-for-action-on-cosets-ii?lq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Take $G=S_3$, $K=\{(),(1,2)\}$, and $L=\{(),(1,2,3),(1,3,2)\}$. We can take $\pi$ to be the identity. Then $G=KL=LK$. Take $g=(1,2)$. Then $g \notin L$, so there is no $l$.

Answer (score 1):

As Jack said, this is not true generally, but if we assume that $K$ is a normal subgroup, then the result would hold true. Let $g\in G$ be an arbitrary element. Since $G=KL=LK$, there exit $k\in K$ and $l\in L$ such that $g=kl$. As you know, $\pi(g)=\phi_g(Kx)=Kxg$ where $Kx$ is a left coset. Hence, one can see that $\pi(g)=\phi_{kl}(Kx)=Kxkl$. Note that $K$ is a normal subgroup. Thus there is $k'$ and such that $xk=k'x$ and so $\pi(g)=\phi_{kl}(Kx)=Kxkl=Kk'xl=Kxl=\pi(l)$.

Comment: This assumes $K$ is normal ($xk = k'x$ means $xkx^{-1} \in K$ for all $x$).

Comment: @JackSchmidt, many thanks to jack. I fixed.