# A second isomorphism theorem for action on cosets II

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group, and $K$, $L$ subgroups of $G$ and $H=K \cap L$ such that:

- $G = \langle K,L \rangle$.
- $\forall g \in G$ : $HgK=KgH$ and $HgL=LgH$

**Remark**: These assumptions imply that $G=KL=LK$, *but the converse is false*,
 because the example of Jack Schmidt [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/692764/a-second-isomorphism-theorem-for-action-on-cosets/692794#692794) doesn't check the second assumption.

Let $\Omega = G/K$ and $\pi: G \to S_{\Omega}$ the canonical action on cosets.

> **Question**: Is it true that $\forall g \in G$ $\exists l \in L $ such that $\pi(g)=\pi(l)$ ?

If yes, then $\forall k \in K$ $\exists s \in K \cap L $ such that $\pi(k)=\pi(s)$, because $ker(\pi) \subset K$.

Comment: This question is harder for me. If K and L are abelian, then H is normal, so K and L are normal. Hence small examples are trivial. However, I don't think H is normal in general, so small examples might not help understand the general case. :-)

Comment: @JackSchmidt: yes, for example if $G=G_1 \times G_2$ and if $H_i$ is a subgroup of $G_i$, then  $K=H_1 \times G_2$ and $L=G_1 \times H_2$ check the assumptions, but $H = K \cap L = H_1 \times H_2$ is not a  normal subgroup of $G$ in general.

Comment: It is equivalent to showing $G=LK^G$, where $K^G$ is $K$'s normal closure. Not sure if this observation helps or not.

Comment: @anon: through your observation, we see that if it's true for $G$ simple,  then $K^G=\{e\}$ or $G$, and $G=L$ or $K$. So we could get a counterexample by finding $G$ simple, with subgroups $K$ and $L$ checking the assumptions and such that $K \cap L \not\in \{K,L \}$; but I don't know yet if such a counterexample exists.

Comment: Sorry, I meant normal core not normal closure.

Comment: @anon: Yes $K^G$ is the [normal core](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Normal_core) of $K$ in $G$.

Comment: @SébastienPalcoux:I got the point.

Comment: See the augmented post: [A second isomorphism theorem for the inclusions of groups](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/159167/a-second-isomorphism-theorem-for-the-inclusions-of-groups)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, $(D_{10} \subset A_6)$ gives a counterexample.

It has exactly two non-trivial intermediate subgroups $K$ and $L$, each isomorphic to $A_5$ (see [here](http://homepages.ulb.ac.be/~tconnor/atlaslat/alt6.pdf)). They  check the assumptions, thanks to a SAGE-GAP computation (see generators [here](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Subgroup_structure_of_alternating_group%3aA6)):

```
sage: G=AlternatingGroup(6)
sage: H=G.subgroup([(1,2,3,4,5),G("(2,5)(3,4)")])
sage: K=G.subgroup([(1,2,3,4,5),(1,2,3)])
sage: L=G.subgroup([(1,2,3,4,5),G("(1,4) (5,6)")])
sage: P1=[Set([G(i)*k*G(j) for i in H for j in K]) for k in G]
sage: P2=[Set([G(j)*k*G(i) for i in H for j in K]) for k in G]
sage: P3=[Set([G(i)*k*G(j) for i in H for j in L]) for k in G]
sage: P4=[Set([G(j)*k*G(i) for i in H for j in L]) for k in G]
sage: P1==P2
True
sage: P3==P4
True
```

Now $KL=A_6$ is simple, so $ker(\pi) = \{ e \}$, but $L \subsetneq G $.
Then $\exists g \in G$ such that $\forall l \in L$ then  $\pi(g) \neq \pi(l)$

**Remark**: The assumptions are not stronger enough for being able to generalize the second isomorphism theorem to  actions on cosets.   We have to find a natural additional assumption.

Comment: See the augmented post: [A second isomorphism theorem for the inclusions of groups](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/159167/a-second-isomorphism-theorem-for-the-inclusions-of-groups)